# Appstore review process and app version update

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, app-update

I have an app waiting for "Pending Developer release". meanwhile i got a bug. So i want to release a new version. As apple says

> You can add a new version of an app when the current version’s status
>   is Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale.

So I am planning to remove the app from sale by deselecting all the territories. Then i will get an option to add a new version and submit it for review. And i want to release the first version itself if the review of second version consumes more time. I think I can make the first version "ready for sale" while second version is waiting for review.

My doubts are:

1. Can I change the status directly from "Pending Developer release" to "Developer Removed from Sale" without going through "Ready for sale" status?
2. Can I submit second version for review while first version status is "Developer removed from sale"?
3. Can I put back the first version for sale, while the second version is in waiting for review status?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but about the review process

Answer (score 0):

1) No, but you can instantly remove it from sale the second it changes to "Ready for Sale".

2) Yes this is fine - I have done this myself a few times.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Answer for second one is fine. Regarding first question, what will be the status if i deselect all territories and save while the app is in "Pending Developer release" status.

Comment: It will still be "Pending Developer Release". You can't remove something from sale that was never actually on sale.

Comment: Ok. It says that app will be stuck in "Pending Developer Release"if i do so and I won't get the option for add a version. Right?

Comment: No you can still submit a new version at "Pending Developer Release". The app has been approved so you can submit a new version.

Comment: Notice you've edited in an extra point to your question. The answer to this is yes as well.

Comment: Thanks. But apple says "You can add a new version of an app when the current version’s status is Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale." Currently my app is in "Pending Developer Release" and i can not find the button to add a new version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68875/discussion-between-minna-zacharias-and-guybrushthreepwood).